# How prevent spray run router at start up?

Tags: scala, spray

Consider a code below:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import spray.can.Http

object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  val handler = system.actorOf(Props[DemoServiceActor], name = "handler")

  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(handler, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
}

import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing.HttpService

class DemoServiceActor extends Actor with DemoService {

  def actorRefFactory = context

  def receive = runRoute(demoRoute)
}

trait DemoService extends HttpService {

  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher

  def demoRoute = {
    path("test") {
      get {
        println("ping")
        complete("test complete")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When `main` runs it print to console `ping`. Why? How to fix this?

Comment: This is expected, see spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/. The route structure is evaluated as eagerly as possible. Either put things into the `complete` directive (`complete { println("ping"); "test complete" }`) or wrap routing parts to be executed dynamically with the `dynamic` directive (http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/execution-directives/dynamic/).

Comment: As this is by far the most surprising thing in spray's routing DSL and the most frequently asked question we changed the behavior in akka-http, see https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/780 for more info.